# Excel: Comparing dates in an Array Formula

Tags: excel, date, comparison-operators, array-formulas

I'm attempting to compare two dates to determine if the tasks were completed on time.

The column range is from **`E7:E200`** for DUE and **`G7:G200`** for COMPLETE date; both columns are formatted the same. I don't want the blank cells to be counted.

I crafted the following array formula:
**`{=SUM(IF(AND($E$7:$E$200=$G$7:$G$200, NOT(ISBLANK($G$7:$G$200),1,0)))))}`**

Excel doesn't throw any errors and neither does it give me the summation when I enter test data. If I use the same formula just 2 cells **`(E7 & G7)`**. it works.

Greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Your formula doesn't work because 1) `AND` won't give you an array as an output, only a single value (TRUE or FALSE) and 2) you have a closing parenthesis in the wrong place. Jeeped has suggested a better alternative (IMO) but you can use * in your version to simulate AND and get the correct results, i.e. with this version `=SUM(IF(($E$7:$E$200=$G$7:$G$200)*NOT(ISBLANK($G$7:$G$200)),1,0))` - confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Hi Barry, @Jeeped
I tried all solutions and all worked very well.
Thank you for your assistance.
vzmon1

Answer (score 2):

A standard (non-array) formula would be,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($E$7:$E$200=$G$7:$G$200)*($G$7:$G$200<>""))
```

While the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) produces array-type processing you do not have to enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Enter with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER:

```
=SUM(IF($E$7:$E$200=$G$7:$G$200,IF($G$7:$G$200<>"",1)))
```

Comment: Hi rwilson:
The system wouldn't allow me to include you in my response, but I wanted to thank you for your support.